# Display json response in ajax jquery,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

The JSON Response I'm getting,

```
     {
        "user_data": {
        "id": 22,
        "first_name": xxx,
        "last_name": xxx,
        "phone_number": "123456789",
        },
        "question_with_answers" : [
            {
           "id": 1,
           "question_name": "Features of our project that you like (select one 
            or more):",
           "answers": [
                {
                "id": 19,
                "question_id": 1,
                "customer_id": 22,
                "option": "Location",
                },
                {
                "id": 20,
                "question_id": 1,
                "customer_id": 22,
                "option": "Architecture",
                 }, 
               ]
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "question_name": "Features of our project that you DID NOT like 
             (select one or more):",
                 "answers": [
                 {
                "id": 22,
                "question_id": 2,
                "customer_id": 22,
                "option": "Location",
                 },

                ]
             },
             {
             "id": 3,
             "question_name": "How soon are you looking to buy a new home?",
             "answers": [
                    {
                       "id": 24,
                       "question_id": 3,
                       "customer_id": 22,
                       "option": "Immediately",
                   }
                 ]
              }
           ]
          }
```

So that is how JSON response looks like, now I need to display data  using jquery

My js code

```
     function openModal(Id){
     var CustomerId = Id;
     $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url: 'customer-details',
        data: {
            'CustomerId':CustomerId
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            //what I have to do here
        }
     })
}
```

The output I want is,

```
first_name : xxx           
last_name  : xxx 
phone_number : 123456789

1.Features of our project that you like (select one or more):
ans: Location, Architecture

2.Features of our project that you DID NOT like (select one or more)
ans: Location

3.How soon are you looking to buy a new home?
ans: Immediately
```

Thats how my output should look like from above json response,Is it possible to get above output using that Json response I got
There are two variable that I have passed from backend like user_data and question_with_answers

Comment: can you add html elements to a page using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Yes I can @marzelin

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the dataType in the $.ajax call, set it to dataType:"json"...

After that, you got on the data variable in the success the json object and you can access it like data.user_data or data.id or data.first_name.

If you dont define the json as dataType, it will not work properly.

## Addition

If you want to display the content of "question_with_answer" you have to iterate trough it, like ....

`for (i in data.question_with_answer) { alert(data.qestion_with_answer[i]); }`

Comment: hello, @rebru I can able to display first object user_data but there is an array in it that is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: How can I display question_with_answers array values

Comment: I did edited my first post, for arrays in objects you have to iterate trough it.

Answer (score 1):

In success handler first of all make your json into a array using

`var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

Now in data you have array of your response and you can use this like

`obj.first_name`

`obj.last_name`

Note:- may be you have issue in `JSON.parse` so use first

`var data = json.stringify(data)`

after that use Json.parse function and use above data variable 
this data

Comment: what second varable data??there are two valiable please take a look

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(data); here data is the json which you get from php and pass in success handler and some time give give error because json convert in string yes I know josn is a string but json have a particular format so its give error if you face error then use  `var data = json.stringify(data)` before json.parse function and in stringify function you pass the json which you used in success handler

may be you got my point both data is same

Comment: I think obj.user_data.first_name will work after parsing.

Comment: @falero80s:- yes you are right user_data skip from my eye thanks to point out